# Html injection in my site

Tags: php, html, code-injection

Well, i have a big problem: All day someone is inserting a HTML code in my index.php and i don't know how, this is the code inserted:

```
<iframe src=**bad url was here** width=0 height=0 frameborder=0></iframe>
```

I already tried this to prevent this problem:

```
$_GET = Sanitize::filter($_GET);
$_POST = Sanitize::filter($_POST)
```

My Sanitize class filter all content in $_gET and $_POST but the problem continue.

This is my Sanitize file:

```
abstract class Sanitize {

/**
 * Filter
 * 
 * @param  mixed $value
 * @param  array $modes
 * @return mixed
 * @static
 * @since  1.0
 */
    static public function filter($value, $modes = array('sql', 'html')) {

        if (!is_array($modes)) {
            $modes = array($modes);
        }

        if (is_string($value)) {
            foreach ($modes as $type) {
              $value = self::_doFilter($value, $type);
            }
            return $value;
        }

        foreach ($value as $key => $toSanatize) {
            if (is_array($toSanatize)) {
                $value[$key]= self::filter($toSanatize, $modes);
            } else {
                foreach ($modes as $type) {
                  $value[$key] = self::_doFilter($toSanatize, $type);
                }
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }

/**
 * DoFilter
 * 
 * @param  mixed $value
 * @param  array $modes
 * @return mixed
 * @static
 * @since  1.0
 */
    static protected function _doFilter($value, $mode) {

        switch ($mode) {
            case 'html':
                $value = strip_tags($value);
                $value = addslashes($value);
                $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
                break;

            case 'sql':
                $value = preg_replace(sql_regcase('/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*| |\\\\)/'),'',$value);
                $value = trim($value);
                break;
        }

        return $value;
    }

}
```

And some files are inserted in my public_html folder , i don't know how.

Comment: I think people will need a little more detail. i.e your whole PHP script for connecting and posting. Along with html, javascript. Look into using prepared statements or PDO for queries.

Comment: What is `Sanitize` and what does `filter()` do? Those aren't standard PHP functions. Is this coming from submitted data or did they embed this into your files?

Comment: Check your system for viruses. Change your password. Set your index.php as read-only. Are there any new/strange files in your root folder?

Comment: I assume that you're using a database to store user data that you're collecting with a <form /> somewhere (see how SO outputs the tag without injection). Even if you ask for a username, the user can enter markup which you will store on your database. What you're not doing is escaping it after read it from database and before you output it. Have a look at [PHP htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) and [PHP htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: any filtering of user input won't change what's already been inserted if that is what is causing it

Comment: User can't send information to database, i don't have any <form> that save in database.

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? there's a chance that you have an infected PC with a pligin in your browser that inserts the code.

Comment: `sql_regcase` is deprecated.  What you are saying is confusing. Is the issue that some has inserted an iframe in your index file? Based on that and that you said there are unknown files I think you have a backdoor that gave access to your site or a file upload vulnerability.   So before you do anything you need to figure out where that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

First, kill this iframe

```
iframe[src="bad url was here"]{
  display: none;
}
```

And change the password and login.